# Can page filtering be moved to the top of list instead of being on the bottom?

Tags: 2013, paging

I was wondering if the filter 1-30 that appears on the bottom of the SharePoint list can be moved to the top instead of the bottom the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript. Here you need to handle three events

Page Load
Next Page Click
Previous Page Click
On all these events execute following function

```
jQuery('#WPQ2_ListTitleViewSelectorMenu_Container').append(jQuery('#scriptPagingWPQ2').clone());
```

Where `scriptPagingWPQ2` is the div element id of the pagination controls.
And `WPQ2_ListTitleViewSelectorMenu_Container` is the span element id of the All Items... control.

You can find these ID using browser developer tools.

Comment: Where do I add the jquery code? using SP designer 2013?

Comment: Yes. You can add the script inside the `AdditionalPageHead` element.

Comment: Where scriptPagingWPQ2 is the div element id of the pagination controls. And WPQ2_ListTitleViewSelectorMenu_Container is the span element id of the All Items... control.  where does that go

Comment: That is the ID my Setup is generating. You should change that to the one on your view page. Use browser developer tool to find that.

Comment: I created a script that works for this. <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#WPQ2_ListTitleViewSelectorMenu_Container').append(jQuery('#scriptPagingWPQ2'));
});

</script>

Comment: ***it doesn't seem to work . remains the same as before, the paging appears at the same bottom like before***

Answer (score 0):

Create a script editor webpart and paste this snippet, this will bring the paging to top.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            jQuery('#WPQ2_ListTitleViewSelectorMenu_Container').append(jQuery('#scriptPagingWPQ2'));
        }
    );
</script>
```